# Windows 8 machine with 3 NIC functioning as a switch

Tags: networking, windows-8, network-adapter

I have a workstation with two machines and one LAN port.

- a mac mini
- a windows tower with Win8 and 3 NICs

How can I set up the windows machine to also function as a switch so that I can run a cable from the LAN port to NIC1 and then a second cable from NIC2 to my Mac mini? I use both machines in parallel and would like to not have to run the mac mini off wifi.

I tried setting up a network bridge on the windows machine but the mac mini only got a self assigned IP with no connection to the rest of the network.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Windows is not a switch, you have to share your internet connection in Windows. That's why it's called ICS, "Internet Connection Sharing".